# "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" for useSelector-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an issue with data imported from redux.
Here is the code:

```
const pathways = useSelector(({ dashboardApp }) => dashboardApp.pathways.data)
  
const levers = useSelector(({ dashboardApp }) => dashboardApp.levers.data)
```

It works perfectly fine for the const levers. But I don't know why it says "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" for the const pathways. (I'm new to redux and react), any tips?

Thank you

Comment: in which line does the error occur?

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, but I figure out that I had imported useSelector from react and not redux....